# Building Java GUI Applications in Embedded Linux (Yocto)

Tags: java, linux, swing, javafx, yocto

I'm pretty new to Developing in Embedded Linux and I'm trying to develop a basic Java based UI application that'll need run on a single board computer with an ARM processor.

I've seen [here](https://jaxenter.com/jdk-arm-without-javafx-end-javafx-embedded-114212.html) and [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/embedded-suite/overview/index.html) that none of the major GUI platforms - JavaFX, Swing and AWT are available with Java Embedded.

I do know that Yocto has a something called SATO to serve as a user interface but I couldn't find much information on it and I'm not sure how to use it develop a GUI application that can run on an Embedded Linux image created through Yocto

I'd really prefer Java but I'm open to other languages too.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I believe C/C++ is a more popular language in Embedded Linux Application development.  I suggest you to use Qt Creator.  Here is a wiki of one of the Yocto Project Board that have the set up http://wiki.hioproject.org/index.php?title=Main_Page